# Every time I attempt to add error bars to my graph it gives me the error below

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

```
sx_mean = sx %>% 
  group_by(modulename) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(pr), SE = sd(pr)/sqrt(length(pr)))


ggplot(data = sx_mean ) +
   geom_point( aes(x = module, y = mean, fill = Value), size = 2.5, color = "seagreen") +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-SE, ymax=mean+SE))
```

> Error in data.frame(list(ymin = c(2.05161888719508, 1.8746390713981,
>   1.28228295778586, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 31

Comment: It doesn't look like you would have variables named `module` or `Value` in the dataset you are using.  Maybe those are floating around in your environment and are the same length as your original dataset instead of the summary dataset?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.